# How to remove words that only appeared once

Tags: database, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataset

```
Id Text
1. Dear Mr. John, your bag order is delivered
2. Dear Mr. Brick, your ball order is delivered
3. Dear Mrs. Blue, your ball purchase is delivered
```

What I need is

```
Id  Text
 1. Dear Mr. your order is delivered
 2. Dear Mr. your ball order is delivered
 3. Dear your ball is delivered
```

So words that only appeared once is removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#split to words and create Series
all_val = df['Text'].str.split(expand=True).stack()
#remove duplicates and join together per first level of MultiIndex
df['Text'] = all_val[all_val.duplicated(keep=False)].groupby(level=0).apply(' '.join)
print (df)
    Id                                   Text
0  1.0       Dear Mr. your order is delivered
1  2.0  Dear Mr. your ball order is delivered
2  3.0            Dear your ball is delivered
```

Or:

```
#join all text together and split by whitespaces
all_val = ' '.join(df['Text']).split()
#get unique values
once = [x for x in all_val if all_val.count(x) == 1]

#remove from text by nested list comprehension
df['Text'] = [' '.join([y for y in x.split() if y not in once]) for x in df['Text']]
#apply alternative
#df['Text'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([y for y in x.split() if y not in once]))
print (df)
    Id                                   Text
0  1.0       Dear Mr. your order is delivered
1  2.0  Dear Mr. your ball order is delivered
2  3.0            Dear your ball is delivered
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
In [78]: s = pd.Series(df.Text.str.cat(sep=' ').split()).value_counts()

In [79]: exp = '|'.join(s[s.eq(1)].index)

In [80]: df.Text.str.replace(exp, '').str.replace('\s\s+', ' ')
Out[80]:
0         Dear Mr. your order is delivered
1    Dear Mr. your ball order is delivered
2              Dear your ball is delivered
Name: Text, dtype: object
```